ArcGIS Pro 3.1 Project Packaging Error 001659
I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where ArcGIS Pro 3.1 is not allowing me to package my project. After getting the ERROR: 001659 several times, I created a new project and re-created my model from scratch, so I know that all of the paths are correct and I haven't moved or deleted any files.  I still get the ERROR: 001659: (C:\GIS510_Spring2024\JMGame_testppk3.ppkx 14 ProjectPackage 2024-04-05 23:28:59 Status: Failed ErrorMessage: ERROR 001659: Consolidating toolbox C:\GIS510_Spring2024\Project_Folders\JMGame_Q2LayoutandModel\JMGame_Q2LayoutandModel.atbx)
I ran the Analyze Tools for Pro tool, and was told there were "No Problems":
Analyzing toolbox JMGameQ2LayoutandModelatbx(C:\GIS510_Spring2024\Project_Folders\JMGame_Q2LayoutandModel\JMGame_Q2LayoutandModel.atbx) for use within ArcGISPro:
No problems
I have a model, which is saved in a Toolbox in my project, which seems to be the root of the problem. I was wondering if you all had any ideas?

I faced it when packaging with custom toolbox. Ended up zipping project folder with scripts embedded in tools
